# How can I use multiple library paths?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to set up an easy to use R development environment for multiple users. R is installed along with a set of other dev tools on an NFS mount.

I want to create a core set of R packages that also live on NFS so n users don't need to install their own copies of the same packages n times. Then, I was hoping users can install one off packages to a local R library. Has anyone worked with an R setup like this before? From the doc, it looks doable by adding both the core package and personal package file paths to `.libPaths()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `.Renviron` file (see `?Startup`).

There are three places to put the file:

- Site wide in `R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site`
- Local in either the current working directory or the home area

In this file you can specify `R_LIBS` and the `R_LIBS_SITE` environment variables.

For your particular problem, you probably want to add the NFS drive location to `R_LIBS_SITE` in the `R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site` file.

---

```
## To get R_HOME
Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
```

Comment: Ok, great. This is really similar to what I had set up as a test. R_LIBS_SITE seems to be automatically set to install_root/library, and setting R_LIBS to a local file path will install packages to the local library. I also see both locations with libPaths() and can search for packages in either library. This is perfect, thanks.

Comment: Depending on your set-up, I set R_LIBS to a location on my hard drive (not a network drive). You don't need to back-up R_LIBS.